# Increment textbox value on button click WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

What I'm trying to do is I have a textbox, and a '-' and a '+' button, and on button click I need to decrease/increase it's value. I have close to 0 experience with WPF, we only learnt console apps in school and now we got this task and I have no idea why this code sample is not working:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace sudokuGUI
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           int ertek = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
           if (ertek > 4)
           {
               textBox1.Text = $"{ertek--}";
           }
       }

       private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           int ertek = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
           if (ertek < 9)
           {
               textBox1.Text = $"{ertek++}";
           }
       }
   }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="sudokuGUI.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:sudokuGUI"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       Title="Sudoku-ellenőrző" Height="210" Width="540">
   <Grid>
       <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="512" Margin="10,90,0,0"/>
       <Label Content="Új feladvány mérete:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
       <Button Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Margin="144,13,0,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
       <Button Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Margin="194,13,0,0" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
       <Label Content="Kezdőállapot:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,59,0,0"/>
       <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Hossz: 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,118,0,0"/>
       <Button Content="Ellenőrzés" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="447,118,0,0"/>
       <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Margin="169,13,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False"/>

   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, as I said I'm a student and I'm not very good at coding yet, also English is not my mother tongue, but basically nothing happens. I get no exception or anything, the textbox's content just doesn't change basically.

Comment: What's the contents of the `TextBox` when you click the button?

Comment: Why not use the [HTML attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) for a textbox that contains a number?  The ability to increment and decrement is included by most browsers.

Comment: @mm8 The content of 'textBox1' (the one I need to change) is 4. So basically I can only go between 4 and 9, so the '-' button is not expected to work right away, but the '+' button should, but what I described above happens (basically nothing).

Answer (score 2):

`ertek++` is a [postfix increment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#postfix-increment-operator). The result of `ertek++` is the value of `ertek` *before* the operation.

use simple `+` operator:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   int ertek = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
   if (ertek < 9)
   {
       textBox1.Text = $"{ertek+1}";
   }
}
```

Comment: It's working perfectly, thanks! I thought those were interchangeable, but guess I was wrong